# Bad parameters given after add product via webservice prestashop

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop

I have createed a simple add product to prestashop via webservice but when I try to add this to the DB  I see only an error *'Bad parameters given'*. What is wrong with my code? And how can I find if a category already exist with webservice?

```
  $reader = new XMLReader;
$reader->open($filename); // open an large xml with products and it should add this to db prestashop via webservice
$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => $shopUrl.'/api/products?schema=blank'));
$resources = $xml->children()->children();
foreach ($resources as $resource) {
  while ($reader->read()) {
    if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) { 
      $name = $reader->name;
    }

    if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT || $reader->nodeType == XMLReader::CDATA){
        switch ($name) {
          case 'id':
           if ($reader->value != '0')
              $resource->id = $reader->value;
            break;

          case 'ilosc':
            $resource->quantity = $reader->value;
            break;

          case 'cena_netto':
            $resource->price = $reader->value;
            break;

          case 'opis':
            $resource->description = $reader->value;
            break;

          case 'waga':
            $resource->weight = $reader->value;
            break;

          case 'kod_kreskowy':
            $resource->ean13 = $reader->value;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'produkt'){
      $reader->next();
      $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
      $xml = $webService->add($opt);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the categories from `categories?schema=blank`, which will return you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<categories>
<category id="1" xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/categories/1"/>
<category id="2" xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/categories/2"/>
<category id="3" xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/categories/3"/>
</categories>
</prestashop>
```

Each of the individual `xlink` will return you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<category>
    <id><![CDATA[2]]></id>
    <id_parent xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/categories/1"><![CDATA[1]]></id_parent>
    <level_depth><![CDATA[1]]></level_depth>
    <nb_products_recursive not_filterable="true"><![CDATA[169]]></nb_products_recursive>
    <active><![CDATA[1]]></active>
    <id_shop_default><![CDATA[1]]></id_shop_default>
    <is_root_category><![CDATA[1]]></is_root_category>
    <position><![CDATA[1]]></position>
    <date_add><![CDATA[2013-08-30 13:06:15]]></date_add>
    <date_upd><![CDATA[2013-08-30 13:06:15]]></date_upd>
    <name><language id="1" xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/languages/1"><![CDATA[Home]]></language><language id="2" xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/languages/2"><![CDATA[Home]]></language></name>
    <link_rewrite><language id="1" xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/languages/1"><![CDATA[home]]></language><language id="2" xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/languages/2"><![CDATA[home]]></language></link_rewrite>
    <description><language id="1" xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/languages/1"><![CDATA[]]></language><language id="2" xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/languages/2"><![CDATA[]]></language></description>
    <meta_title><language id="1" xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/languages/1"><![CDATA[]]></language><language id="2" xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/languages/2"><![CDATA[]]></language></meta_title>
    <meta_description><language id="1" xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/languages/1"><![CDATA[]]></language><language id="2" xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/languages/2"><![CDATA[]]></language></meta_description>
    <meta_keywords><language id="1" xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/languages/1"><![CDATA[]]></language><language id="2" xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/languages/2"><![CDATA[]]></language></meta_keywords>
<associations>
<categories node_type="category">
    <category xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/categories/3">
    <id><![CDATA[3]]></id>
    </category>
    <category xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/categories/4">
    <id><![CDATA[4]]></id>
    </category> 
    </category>
</categories>
<products node_type="product">
    <product xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/products/22">
    <id><![CDATA[22]]></id>
    </product>
    <product xlink:href="http://www.yourshop/api/products/24">
    <id><![CDATA[24]]></id> 
</products>
</associations>
</category>
</prestashop>
```